# What is the recommended gap between boards when adding a subfloor?

Tags: subfloor

I am laying a 3/4 inch subfloor over a 2” foam barrier. Do the subfloor boards butt up against each other or should there be a gap? I’m presuming a small gap to avoid squeaking? And if a gap, so they need to be caulked?

Comment: What sort of subfloor are you laying material-wise?

Comment: Treated plywood